# Throttling comments

Tags: php, laravel, throttling

I want to make it so a user can only post 1 comment per minute at most.

I've tried simply using the `throttle` middleware and it is not working. I can still post comments every second.

Route code:

```
Route::post('comment/{id}', 'HomeController@comment')->name('comment')->middleware('throttle');
```

Controller code:

```
public function comment($id)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        "body" => "required",
    ]);

    $jersey = Jersey::findOrFail($id);
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $comment->jersey_id = $jersey->id;
    $comment->body = request()->input('body');
    $comment->save();
    activity()->by(auth()->user())->withProperties($comment)->log('Commented');
    request()->session()->flash('status', 'Comment submitted!');

    return redirect()->route('concept', $id);
}
```

How do I make it so that it will flash an error instead of saving if the user is attempting to post more than 1 comment per minute?

Comment: The throttle middleware is a core feature of Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle package.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I'm using throttle in route group like that:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:1'], function () {
    // Your routes here
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@comment')->name('comment');
    // ...
)}
```

But in your case you can modify your code with specifying throttle parameters like that:

```
Route::post('comment/{id}', 'HomeController@comment')->name('comment')->middleware('throttle:1');
```

Don't forget to clear caches to apply changes.